# Adding a child component to a JButton

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jbutton

Is it possible to place a child component inside a `JButton` and make it transparent to a subset of mouse events so that:

- The child component receives `MouseMotionEvent`s (so it can respond by modifying a displayed image)
- Clicking still depresses the `JButton` "behind" the child component

If you add the child component to the button but make no other changes, clicking in the area occupied by the child does not activate the button.

I know this can be achieved by creating a new class that extends `JButton` but I would prefer to use a child component which has already been written.

Note: this is purely for cosmetic reasons.  The child component only changes its own appearance.  It does not perform any other actions in response to clicks.  There is just one `Action`, triggered by the button in the normal way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible but probably there are better ways to change the appearance of a JButton on mouse over. You can extend a ButtonUI to do that. However, if you want to drop a component over a JButton, you should pass other mouse events (e.g clicks) to the underlying JButton.

Comment: I used SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent to pass unwanted events to the button, which gives the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

JXLayer is just the thing you need. Check out https://jxlayer.dev.java.net/
The project site has several good articles about JXLayer's usage for many different use cases.