# How to add Mouse listener to an ImageIcon embedded in a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I want to have a clickable icon (an ImageIcon object) inside a JLabel. How can I add a MouseListener or any ActionListener just to that Icon. Is there any other way to know if the icon has been clicked? I use the setIcon() method for the JLabel to set its icon.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not a `JButton` with an `Icon`?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281612/adding-a-child-component-to-a-jbutton

Comment: A `JButton`'s icon indeed responds to a mouse event while a `JLabel`'s doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

You could have two separate JLabel inside a container, the first with text, the second with just the icon, and add a mouse listener to the icon JLabel.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a clever way of doing it using the mouse event's X and Y position and seeing if it was inside the bounds of the Icon, but alas the Rectangle that describes the Icon's position within a JLabel is private inside the LabelUI, so even subclassing the LabelUI wouldn't give you access to it.  It does, however, call SwingUtilities.layoutCompoundLabel(), one parameter of which is the Icon's Rectangle, so you could, if you realllly wanted, subclass SwingUtilities to intercept that information and store it somewhere.  But really, I wouldn't bother.  Just use two components.

Answer (score 1):

This method is very hacky but worked for me.

```
    JLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me){
            try {
                Robot robot = new Robot();
                if(JLabel.getBounds().contains(me.getPoint()) && !robot.getPixelColor(me.getXOnScreen(),me.getYOnScreen()).equals(page.getBackground())){
                    //Do action here
                }
            } catch (AWTException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -4):

you can use this code to solving your problem:

```
public  class Test extends JFrame {
    private JLabel label;
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("example.gif");
    public Test(){
        label = new JLabel(icon);
        label.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        //for example    
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello");

        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: This doesn't help the original poster with his problem.  He knows how to create and use a MouseListener but rather wants to listen to just the image portion of the JLabel.